NestJS module setup for test
I want to test my mall service in mall.service.spec.ts.
Please help why npm is not working.
// mall.service.spec.ts

describe('MallService', () => {
  let service: MallService

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, TestRepository])],
      controllers: [MallController],
      providers: [
        MallService,
        {
          provide: IUSER_REPOSITORY,
          useClass: TestRepository,
        },
      ],
    }).compile()

    service = module.get<MallService>(MallService)
  })

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined()
  })
})

// mall.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class MallService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(IUSER_REPOSITORY)
    private readonly userRepository: IUserRepository,
  ) {}
...
}

what is the problem with module setup?
when I run for test, it says like below.
 - Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MallController (?). Please
   make sure that the argument MallService at index [0] is available in
   the RootTestModule context.
   
   Potential solutions:
     - Is RootTestModule a valid NestJS module?
     - If MallService is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
     - If MallService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
       @Module({
           imports: [ /* the Module containing MallService */ ]
         })*


I believe you have to override the provider, like below.
More can be read in the NestJS Docs
// mall.service.spec.ts

describe('MallService', () => {
  let service: MallService

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, TestRepository])],
      controllers: [MallController],
      providers: [
        MallService,
        IUSER_REPOSITORY,
      ],
    }).overrideProvider(IUSER_REPOSITORY)
      .useValue(TestRepository)
      .compile()

    service = module.get<MallService>(MallService)
  })

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined()
  })
})

